# NextJS How to add styles based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `nextjs`-application, I have a `<Button>`-component which `background-color` and `text-color` are based on which theme is selected.

So I created a `Button.module.css`:

```
.btn {
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 31px
 }

.primaryOrange {
   background-color:#f06415 ;
   color: #fff
}

.secondaryOrange {
   color:#f06415;
   background-color: #fff
}

.primaryBlue {
  background-color: #2e3149;
  color: #fff;
}

.secondaryBlue {
  background-color:#fff;
  color: #2e3149;
}
```

then, in my `Button`-component I tried this:

```
import styles from "./Button.module.css"

interface IButton {
  text?: string
  theme?: string
  onClick: () => void
}

export default function Button({ theme, text }: IButton) {
   return (
     <button
        className={`${styles.btn} ${
          theme === "primaryOrange"
          ? styles.primaryOrange
          : styles.secondaryOrange
       } ${theme === "primaryBlue" 
          ? styles.primaryBlue 
          : styles.secondaryBlue}
        `}
      >
       {text}
    </button>
  )
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library called 'clsx' it will help with writing something like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).